# How to add 5 minute javascript countdown timer which submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, timer

I want to add 5 minute countdown timer which submit a form to my php page.

```
        <form name="myfm" id="myfm" method="post" action="Quiz.php">
        <table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30><td></td></td></tr> <table border=0>
        <?php $n=$n+1; ?>
        <tr><td>Question  <?php echo $n." "; echo $row[2]; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=1><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8> <input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]" value=2><?php echo $row[4];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=3><?php echo $row[5];?></td></tr>
        <tr><td class=style8><input type="radio" name="ques['<?php echo $n; ?>'][]"  value=4><?php echo $row[6];?></td></tr>

    <?php 
        }
        echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit id='result' value='Get Result'></form>";
        ?>
        </table></table>
        </form>
```

Please help me..I am doing a quiz page that automatically submit form when countdown ends.Thankyou...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want, I used a while ago - 
https://jsfiddle.net/v5uc9wfx/3/

```js
function CountDown(duration, display) {
    if (!isNaN(duration)) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

        var interVal = setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
            if (--timer < 0) {
                timer = duration;
                SubmitFunction();
                $(display).empty();
                clearInterval(interVal)
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Here -

```js
CountDown(duration, display)
```

Duration is passed in seconds, i.e. 300 second= 5 Minutes. display is another parameter you want to display where.

You might need to clear interval as well-

```js
clearInterval(interVal)
```

With form

```js
        function CountDown(duration, display) {
            if (!isNaN(duration)) {
                var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
                
              var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                    $(display).html("<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
                    if (--timer < 0) {
                        timer = duration;
                       SubmitFunction();
                       $('#display').empty();
                       clearInterval(interVal)
                    }
                    },1000);
            }
        }
        
        function SubmitFunction(){
       $('form').submit();
        
        }
    
         CountDown(300,$('#display'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">

</div>
<form action="/" >
<lable>Name: <input type="text"></lable>

</form>
```

Comment: i have to use ->         function SubmitFunction(){
       $('#myfm').html('quiz');
        
        }    <- right?

Comment: @SibyXavier, No the form you want to submit with the query answers. 
Have a look another demo for your purpose

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v5uc9wfx/4/
in this link I am submitting form as soon as countdown comes down to 0 
so your quiz form will take place there. 
as you said - `"I am doing a quiz page that automatically submit form when countdown ends"`

Comment: thankyou manoz....have to click submit button so i wrote                       function SubmitFunction(){
        $('#result').click();
        
        }
    it works...

Answer (score 3):

```js
/*timer*/

      var seconds = 300;
      function secondPassed() {
          var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
              remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

          if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
              remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
          }

          document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
          if (seconds == 0) {
              clearInterval(countdownTimer);
             //form1 is your form name
            document.form1.submit();
          } else {
              seconds--;
          }
      }
      var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```css
.timer {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
            <time id="countdown">5:00</time>
        </div>
<form action="index.php" name="form1" id="form1">
```

Comment: better answer but incomplete and code only answers are not good post your thoughts about your answer, what are you trying to say to OP.

Comment: I don't know what you think about OP?

Comment: timer ok but how to submit form?

Comment: Now my answer is completed.

Comment: Adding some explanation could help him understand easily

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Window setTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to call submit form after 5 minutes

```
setTimeout(function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}, 60*1000*5);
```

Comment: he will first have to prevent the default form submission

Comment: @antoniskamamis - Why?

Comment: @nnnnnn if the form submits the timer will not matter anymore. the page will change

Comment: @antoniskamamis this answer has an idea but OP may be needs a timer visually showing coundown.

Comment: @Jai again if the form submits, no timer will be visible in the page. a new page request will be issued and a new page will be displayed

Comment: @antoniskamamis that's fine but how a user on that quiz know how much time has been left to post the answer? This is where countdown is required visually and yes this answer is also incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout()` will fire a function `SubmitForm` after `300000` milliseconds = 5 minutes.

```
function SubmitForm(){
    $("form").submit();
};
setTimeout(SubmitForm,300000);//5*60*1000
```

Comment: Typing mistake, changed

Comment: what?? `300 < 1000 ms` still wrong and code only answers are tend to be deleted/flagged, so better to post some explanations about your thoughts.

Comment: instead of calculating it, one should use it like: `5*60*1000` as suggested in the other answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
var trig = setInterval(timer,1000);

    var counter=0;
    var min=4;
    var sec=60;

    function timer(){

    sec=--sec;

    if(sec===0){
    min=--min;
    sec=59;
    counter=++counter;
    }

    if(counter===5){
    sec=0;
    min=0;
    clearInterval(trig);
     functionSubmit();
     document.write("Submitted");
     }

     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = min+" : "+sec;

     }
```

```html
<p>Autosubmit in <span id="output"></span></p>
```