# Display hours in countdown timer javascript

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I somehow copied this code from stackoverflow, but I forgot the link. I noticed that if I try to input hours, this will be converted into minutes which is very odd to look.

```js
var hms = "02:30:00";
 var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

 // minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
 var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 

  if(seconds > 0)
  { 

       function secondPassed() {
          
          
           var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
               remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

           if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
               remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
           }

           document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = ":" +minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
           if (seconds == 0) {
               clearInterval(countdownTimer);
              //form1 is your form name
             document.form_quiz.submit();
           } else {
               seconds--;
           }
       }
       var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

       }
```

```css
time{

color:red;

}
```

```html
02:30:00 <br>

<time id="countdown">02:30:00</time>
```

The countdown should display like 02:29:59 after ( 1 second passes ). and not 149:59.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Probably what you're referencing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35361861/975624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have forget to calculate hour time.

Try like this ==>

```js
var hms = "02:30:00";
 var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

 // minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
 var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 

  if(seconds > 0)
  { 

       function secondPassed() {
          
          
           var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60),
               remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
                   var hour   =Math.floor((minutes)/60);
                    minutes = minutes%60;

           if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
               remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
           }
              hour = ("0" + hour).slice(-2);
              minutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
              remainingSeconds= ("0" + remainingSeconds).slice(-2);

           document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = hour +":" +minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
           if (seconds == 0) {
               clearInterval(countdownTimer);
              //form1 is your form name
             document.form_quiz.submit();
           } else {
               seconds--;
           }
       }
       var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

       }
```

```css
time{

color:red;

}
```

```html
02:30:00 <br>

<time id="countdown">02:30:00</time>
```