# Google APP SCRIPT -> Force submit a google form after a given duration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a script that could stop and submit the entire form after a given duration.
The duration have to be set in the script settings when creating the form.
I will use this functionality in order to evaluate students.

I did not understood anything in the google documentation, so I don't know how to stop the form and how to wait the duration (like the setTimeOut function in javascript).

Can you help me please ?

Waykizz

Answer (score 3):

This cannot currently be done using native Google forms.

You could use HTMLService to create your own form and could add the time controls to it using client-side javascript. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013693/google-forms-file-upload-complete-example) covers the creation of the form. Be warned that this is much more complex than using Google forms. As for the timer/autosubmit part of it see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361637/how-to-add-5-minute-javascript-countdown-timer-which-submit-a-form).